# How to create webhook of quickbooks using nodejs api?

Tags: node.js, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, nodejs-server

I was tried to implement webhook of quickbooks in nodejs api for get realtime data related to customer for update and insert in my sql database but not got any proper reference and found solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickbooks webhooks can be easily implemented in node.js, here is git repo with sample code.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-WebhookNotifications-nodejs

If you are new to quickbooks integration and would like to test if webhooks are received or not then you shall use https://requestbin.com/ to create online webhook receiver. Which will consume any payload sent to it. Thus you will know what kind of response body to expect when coding in node.js

Here is official step  by step guide for webhook implementation

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/webhooks

Do share specific error if any

Answer (score 0):

To make a webhook in nodejs. You can use [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) or [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/). Create a post method in it and you are good to go.

Comment: We are using nodejs, expressjs for that. and we need to use webhook of quickbooks not a only webhook.

Comment: That webhook will be called by quickbook right. So what do you mean by, "we need to use"?